# MIME type error when integration react app with FCM

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate my react app with Firebase to implement push notifications. I have this file with all configurations inside my src folder :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

const config = {
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL",
    projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
    appId: "APP_ID",
    measurementId: "MEASURE_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

export const requestFirebaseNotificationPermission = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        messaging
            .requestPermission()
            .then(() => messaging.getToken())
            .then((firebaseToken) => {
                resolve(firebaseToken);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });

export const onMessageListener = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
            resolve(payload);
        });
    });
```

And, here is how I implement the function to make push notifications work out inside my App.js :

```
 // Load the FCM configuration parameters and activate the push notifications through the app
        requestFirebaseNotificationPermission()
            .then((firebaseToken) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log("CHECK_FCM_TOKEN", firebaseToken);
                this.setState({ fcmToken: firebaseToken })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return err;
            });
```

This is the error that I always get and I am stuck since long with no solutions at all :
[image: Check the error screenshot here]

If there could be any help to fix this, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar issue. The problem was i was not loading the service worker file properly.

Place your service worker file in public folder and try accessing it.
For eg: my service worker file(firebase-messaging-sw.js) was placed in public folder. So if i open http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js i can view the js file.

Before react was trying to fetch this file and returned an html(default index page) file and caused to return MIME type error.